# Calibration of Germanium Detector with Eu-152

Tags: particle-detectors, gamma-rays

I'm trying to find the branching ratio for Na-22. For that, I need to calibrate my detector sensitivity for different evergy levels.
For that, I measured Eu-152 gamma spectrum, and now I wish to reference it to known values.

I've been desperately Googling any query I can think of to find the required data, but I didn't find anything. Many articles discuss this technique, but none of the ones I found actually provide the data. It's pretty strange I can't find anything. Perhaps I'm minsterpreting what I read, maybe because English isn't my mother tongue?

Does anyone have a reference for known branching ratios for Eu-152? That would be very helpful! Thanks!

Edit:
I found the following:
https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwja44T4-6HRAhUJVhoKHaYpBeoQFggoMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bipm.org%2Futils%2Fcommon%2Fpdf%2FmonographieRI%2FMonographie_BIPM-5_Comments_Vol1-5.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHuD1hOIpj1TdimykYlIRFp2KF49Q&sig2=LZFeIV6F05iHMd4LHNwmJg&bvm=bv.142059868,d.d24&cad=rja

But I can't seem to interpret it... The values they describe as "probabilities" do not sum to 1 (nor to 100) and I can't find a description of these statistics anywhere. Some other articles present similar data. But what does it mean?

Comment: Try this paper: http://www.rrp.infim.ro/2012_64_4/art06Neacsu.pdf

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate on the interpretation of these results?

Comment: edit (misclicked Enter): Thank you. Can you elaborate on the interpretation of these results? In eq. (2) they explain the calculation, but still the emission probabilities, which are the key factor of the results in the table to be meaningful, are missing...

Comment: Here's a better resource: http://www.nucleide.org/DDEP_WG/Nuclides/Eu-152_tables.pdf

Comment: From the probabilities in the tables you can calculate the relative intensities and use those to calculate the energy-dependent detector efficiencies.  Enjoy

Comment: Ok, I managed to figure out the interpretation of the above data. That was my main concern that kept me from understanding the data in your references. I'll add the reference that presented the required explanations. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So what was missing for me is the explanation as to how to interpret the information in all the different papers, i.e. how exactly the efficiency is calculated, and also what $I_\gamma$ means.

If anyone else also gets mixed up by these definitions, here is a very reference I found very informative:

https://owlcation.com/stem/Gamma-Ray-Spectroscopy